# Pra que serve o atributo "behavior" no CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Já vi em alguns códigos CSS feitos para funcionar no <del>belissimo navegador</del> Internet Explorer o seguinte atributo:

```
img {
  behavior: url(ie_png.htc);
}
```

Qual é a finalidade desse `behavior`?

Só funciona para o Internet Explorer?

Comment: Nossa, você tirou isso do fundo do baú.

Comment: Sério @bfavaretto? Eu já tinha visto num código e quis saber pra que servia. Um dia já usei pra fazer um border-radius funcionar no internet explorer, mas nunca soube o que é esse tal de HTC nem mesmo behavior

Comment: Eu vou pesquisar pra refrescar a memória e poder postar uma resposta completa. Mas já adianto: no caso do seu exemplo, o *behavior* servia para fazer os IEs velhos respeitarem a transparência (canal alpha) em arquivos PNG.

Comment: Desisti de responder, o Earendul não diz tudo mas diz o suficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, só funciona para Internet Explorer.

É uma extensão da Microsoft para CSS.

**O que ele faz?**

Seta ou busca a localização do script de comportamento de um elemento [Dynamic HTML (DHTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms531079(v=vs.85).aspx).

Normalmente são arquivos .htc, compostos por HTML, scripts e elementos específicos de HTC.

### Sintaxe

```
behavior: url(sLocation) | url(#objID) | url(#default#behaviorName)
```

### Propriedades

**`url(sLocation)`**

- Implementação do script de comportamento DHTML, onde sLocation é uma URL absoluta ou relativa.

**`url(#objID)`**

- Implementação binária do comportamento DHTML, onde objID é a ID especificada na tag do objeto.

**`url(#default#behaviorName)`**

- O comportamento padrão da aplicação, identificado por seu behaviorName.

Um exemplo de seu uso é um componente que implementa a transparência alpha de imagens PNG para o IE 5.5 e IE 6. [TwinHelix Designs](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/).

Fontes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339276/what-is-behavior-url-property-in-css
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/behavior

Comment: Very large workaround in Internet explorer

Comment: Parabéns. Obrigado pela resposta ;)